# OffsetDateTime fails with localized formatter using FormatStyle of LONG or FULL

Tags: java, date-formatting, java-time, timezone-offset

## tl;dr

This fails.

```
OffsetDateTime.now()
              .format( 
                  DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.LONG )
              )  // throws DateTimeException.
```

But the same moment with same offset in a `ZonedDateTime` works.

Why?

## Details

When letting [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) automatically localize the string representation of a [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) via [`DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofLocalizedDateTime-java.time.format.FormatStyle-java.time.format.FormatStyle-), calling [`format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#format-java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter-) works if the formatter carries a [`FormatStyle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html) of `SHORT` or `MEDIUM`. But when the formatter carries [`LONG`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html#LONG) or [`FULL`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html#FULL), a [`DateTimeException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DateTimeException.html) is thrown. Yet [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) succeeds using the same moment with the same [offset](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html). Why?

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.LONG ) ;

OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.now( ZoneId.systemDefault() ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant( odt.getOffset() ) ;  // Generate a `ZonedDateTime` with same moment and same offset as the `OffsetDateTime`.

// Succeeds.
String outputZdt = zdt.format( f ) ;
System.out.println( "outputZdt: " + outputZdt ) ;

// Fails. Throws exception.
if ( false ) {
String outputOdt = odt.format( f ) ;  // Throws exception.
System.out.println( "outputOdt: " + outputOdt ) ;
}
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/ndLWAD).

When run…

The good.

> outputZdt: September 16, 2017 8:42:14 AM Z

The bad.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to extract value: class java.time.OffsetDateTime
    at java.time.format.DateTimePrintContext.getValue(DateTimePrintContext.java:282)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder$ZoneTextPrinterParser.format(DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:3682)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder$CompositePrinterParser.format(DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:2179)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder$LocalizedPrinterParser.format(DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:4347)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder$CompositePrinterParser.format(DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:2179)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.formatTo(DateTimeFormatter.java:1746)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.format(DateTimeFormatter.java:1720)
    at java.time.OffsetDateTime.format(OffsetDateTime.java:1674)
    at Ideone.main(Main.java:28)
```

I wrote the core of that code to work around the exception thrown, `odt.atZoneSameInstant( odt.getOffset() )`. Then I realized, why doesn’t `java.time` do the same thing internally? Why should the `OffsetDateTime` fail to format where a `ZonedDateTime` with the same moment and the same offset succeeds? Why should I need to do this conversion from `OffsetDateTime` to `ZonedDateTime`?

➟ Is this behavior of `OffsetDateTime` formatting failure a bug or a feature?

I would file a bug report, but I want to make sure I am misunderstanding something.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like the Javadoc bug reported [here](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8085887). In the example provided they use `LocalDateTime`, but the behavior is the same.

The use of `FormatStyle.LONG` and `FormatStyle.FULL` [seems](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2016-March/039451.html) to require a `ZoneId` which `OffsetDateTime` does not have

> Please review `java.time` javadoc improvements to highlight a common 
>   misunderstanding about formatting elements that require a timezone in
>   addition to the time.
>
> When using locale specific formatting, it may work if the locale 
>   formatting does not require a timezone or fail if the locale
>   formatting requires a timezone and a timezone is not provided.

which is why [they clarified the javadoc](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/dev/jdk/rev/28df1af8e872) to mention

```
* The {@code FULL} and {@code LONG} styles typically require a time-zone.
* When formatting using these styles, a {@code ZoneId} must be available,
* either by using {@code ZonedDateTime} or {@link DateTimeFormatter#withZone}.
```

---

You could create the `DateTimeFormatter` with the `OffsetDateTime`'s `ZoneOffset`.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.LONG)
                                  .withZone(odt.getOffset());
```

in which case the `OffsetDateTime` will be converted to a `ZonedDateTime` before formatting occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Debugging the code, I've found that the formatter ends up in [this line](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java#3662) (grepcode's line is not exactly the same number of my JDK installation, but the code is):

```
ZoneId zone = context.getValue(TemporalQueries.zoneId());
```

It tries to extract the zone, using the built-in query `TemporalQueries.zoneId()`. According to [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalQueries.html#zoneId--), this query returns `null` if the temporal object is an `OffsetDateTime`:

> Thus a ZonedDateTime will return the result of getZone(), but an OffsetDateTime will return null.

You can confirm this by calling `odt.query(TemporalQueries.zoneId())` - it returns `null` indeed.

Later, the result of this query is [checked by a `DateTimePrintContext`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/time/format/DateTimePrintContext.java#281):

```
R result = temporal.query(query);
if (result == null && optional == 0) {
    throw new DateTimeException("Unable to extract value: " + temporal.getClass());
}
```

As the `result` is `null`, it throws the exception.

---

Actually, trying to get the zone name (pattern `z`) from an `OffsetDateTime` will throw an exception:

```
// java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to extract value: class java.time.OffsetDateTime
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("z").format(OffsetDateTime.now());
```

Because this pattern ends up in the problematic line described above.

And checking the date style for all locales, using `getLocalizedDateTimePattern`:

```
// did this for all locales
DateTimeFormatterBuilder.getLocalizedDateTimePattern(FormatStyle.LONG, FormatStyle.LONG,
    IsoChronology.INSTANCE, locale);
```

I didn't check all, but most of them have the lowercase `z` pattern, which means that it will fail for most (if not all) locales.

---

Not directly related, but as you're calling `atZoneSameInstant` with a `ZoneOffset` as parameter, you could simply call `odt.toZonedDateTime()` instead.